# Multiple layouts for one Angular 2 UI Component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components, angular-components, angular-template

I would like to create a **UI component** (like a datepicker) for **Angular >=2** with **different layouts**. For example: one for ng-bootstrap and another one for Angular Material 2.

I was thinking in this:

```
<div *ngIf="template === 1"> Bootstrap </div>
<div *ngIf="template === 2"> Angular Material </div>
```

Not only this is an **ugly solution**, but I don't think it would work because  there would be a conflict between ng-bootstrap and material2.

Another solution would be to create two different components:

```
<my-ng-bootstrap-component> Bootstrap </my-ng-bootstrap-component>
<my-material2-component> Angular Material </my-material2-component>
```

But this is not what I need. Because that would be very confusing for users of the component.

Any ideas ?

**Edit:** also, it should share some logic between them. Probably inheritance ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like maybe an [attribute directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) to simply apply the classes/components/functions that each style framework could need. Then the implementation would be nice and readable `<ui-component material></ui-component>` or `<ui-component bootstrap></ui-component>`.

Comment: @filoxo can you add a template to an attribute directive ?

Comment: No. Think of a directive as a template-less component. But it can be used to dynamically create a component that you can pass back to the host. A good example of this that I've seen is the [Angular Material tooltip](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tooltip/tooltip.ts). If that seems too difficult or unnecessary, the above could simply be `@Input`s on the component.

Comment: @filoxo So there will be two directives and two components, right ? So is this [dynamic component loading](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html) ? Can it be set a "default" template based on the lack of directives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer from @filoxo but he deleted his answer

Copy from his comment:

> It sounds like maybe an attribute directive to simply apply the classes/components/functions that each style framework could need. Then the implementation would be nice and readable `<ui-component material></ui-component>` or `<ui-component bootstrap></ui-component>`